# Limit of $\sum_{d}\sum_{c\neq0}\left(\frac{1}{cz+d}-\frac{1}{cz+d+1}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, modular-forms

To evaluate $$\sum_{d\in\mathbb Z}\sum_{c\in\mathbb Z\smallsetminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{1}{cz+d}-\frac{1}{cz+d+1}\right)$$ where $z$ on the upper half plane of $\mathbb C$.

We first consider a finite sum on $d$.
$$\sum_{d=N}^{n-1}\sum_{c\in\mathbb Z\smallsetminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{1}{cz+d}-\frac{1}{cz+d+1}\right)=\sum_{c\in\mathbb Z\smallsetminus\{0\}}\sum_{d=N}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{cz+d}-\frac{1}{cz+d+1}\right)=\sum_{c\in\mathbb Z\smallsetminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{1}{cz-N}-\frac{1}{cz+N}\right).$$

$$=\frac{1}{z}\sum_{c\in\mathbb Z\smallsetminus\{0\}}\left(\frac{1}{c-N/z}-\frac{1}{c+N/z}\right)=\frac{1}{z}\left(\sum_{c\neq0}\frac{1}{c-N/z}+\sum_{c\neq0}\frac{1}{-c-N/z}\right)$$
We set $-N/z:=\tau$. Use the following Fourier expansion $$\frac{1}{\tau}+\sum_{c\neq0}\frac{1}{c+\tau}(=\pi\cot(\pi\tau))=\pi i-2\pi i\sum_{m>0}\exp(2\pi im\tau).$$

We can see that the only term that survives is $\pi i$ in both Fourier series when $N\to\infty$. So the result is $\color{red}{+}\frac{2\pi i}{z}$. But it should be $\color{red}{-}\frac{2\pi i}{z}$ because of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271002/question-about-weight-2-eisenstein-series).
I doublechecked serveral times but I could not find my mistake(s)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for the Fourier series is off. It should be

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\tau}+\sum_{c\neq 0}\frac{1}{c+\tau}&=\pi i-2\pi i\sum_{m=0}\exp(2\pi im\tau)\\
&=\pi i-2\pi i-2\pi i\sum_{m>0}\exp(2\pi i m\tau)\\
&=-\pi i-2\pi i\sum_{m>0}\exp(2\pi i m\tau),
\end{align*}
which hopefully fixes your error.
I've seen some authors start this sum at $m=0$ and others at $m=1$ so there is definitely cause for confusion.

Comment: Thank you! It helps. And that was exactly the error. But the formula a bit "weird" that there was already a constant term but it is included again in the sum.